# maven assembly- to ignore dependency of zip dependancy

Tags: dependencies, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

When specifying dependency of type ZIP, 
Is it possible to ignore its dependencies once packaging/assembling the artifact?

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>com.groupId.</groupId> 
  <artifactId>testProject</artifactId> 
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> 
  <type>zip</type> 
</dependency>
```

I tried * as exclude in the assembly file, but it doesn't seems like it have any effect

```
<assembly>
  <id>release</id>
  <formats>
    <format>dir</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>*</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </moduleSet>
  </moduleSets>
</assembly>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to `exclude` *transitive dependencies* of one specific `dependency`, which is of type `zip`.

```
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <includes>
        <include>com.groupId:testProject:zip</exclude>
        <useTransitiveDependencies>false</useTransitiveDependencies>
      </includes>
    </dependencySet>
    ....
  </dependencySets>
```

You would use `moduleSet` in a multi-module project.